# permutation tests of group differences when data contain repeated measures

Tags: repeated-measures, permutation-test

I have data from several mice with id `id`. Each mouse either belongs to either group `C` or group `T`. I also have a repeated measures factor because each mouse wandered around two mazes (`A` and `B`). My dependent variable is `score`.

```
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6), 
         maze=c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", 
                "A", "B"), 
         group=c("C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C",
                 "T", "T"), 
         score=c(10, 21, 13, 9, 12, 16, 3, 18, 3, 19, 22, 20))

   id maze group score
1   1    A     C    10
2   1    B     C    21
3   2    A     T    13
4   2    B     T     9
5   3    A     C    12
6   3    B     C    16
7   4    A     T     3
8   4    B     T    18
9   5    A     C     3
10  5    B     C    19
11  6    A     T    22
12  6    B     T    20
```

I'm familiar with permutation tests when each row is an independent observation, but if I'm interested in the effect of `group`, how should the shuffling be done? Can I simply shuffle the group labels randomly in every replicate, even though `scores` are not truly independent?

EDIT:
For example, I wondered if I should only shuffle the `group` labels, with the constraint that each `id` should get the same `group` label:

```
   id maze group score
1   1    A     T    10
2   1    B     T    21
3   2    A     C    13
4   2    B     C     9
5   3    A     C    12
6   3    B     C    16
7   4    A     C     3
8   4    B     C    18
9   5    A     T     3
10  5    B     T    19
11  6    A     C    22
12  6    B     C    20
```

randomly shuffling the `group` labels would break the correlation structure. For example, with the random shuffling of `group` labels below, `id 1` now belongs to both groups, even though it was originally in `group T` only. Would this be valid?

```
   id maze group score
1   1    A     T    10
2   1    B     C    21
3   2    A     C    13
4   2    B     C     9
5   3    A     T    12
6   3    B     C    16
7   4    A     T     3
8   4    B     C    18
9   5    A     T     3
10  5    B     T    19
11  6    A     T    22
12  6    B     C    20
```

Comment: The answer depends on your null hypothesis.  What is it?

Comment: @whuber, that there is no difference in `scores` between mice in group `C` and group `T`. If there were no repeated measures (`maze`) this would be straightforward, but I'm not sure how to do the shuffling once observations are not independent anymore.

Comment: Your null hypothesis tells you how to do the shuffling: assuming no difference in scores, the assignment of "C" or "T" to each subject would not matter and therefore can be randomized.  Presumably it was randomized as part of your experimental design, anyway.

Comment: @whuber, thanks for the comment. Yes, I understand that the `C` and `T` labels should be shuffled, the question is rather how to deal with the fact that randomly shuffling group labels will likely make some ids belonging to both groups, since the data have repeated measures (`maze`). 
I edited my question which I hope clarifies my problem.

Comment: I don't follow: when you shuffle the mice, of course you keep the measurements of each mouse attached to it.  You cannot justify shuffling the measurements among mice because you expect the measurements for any given mouse not to be independent.  (They will only be *conditionally* independent, if that.)  All your model and null hypothesis allow you to change are the *assignments* of mice to control and treatment groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each mouse belongs to one group. Having it run through one or many mazes has no influence on your null ("that there is no difference in scores between mice in group C and group T") so we keep that structure in place and do not permute that.

The procedure is very similar to that in your previous question here: [Permutations with repeated measures](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/587560/117812)

Pivot the data to a wide format where each mouse has one row with one column defining the group. Then permute the one row (which group each mouse belongs to). Everything else needs no manipulation.

We know that some mouse got 10 points in maze A and 21 in maze B and we only need to permute, if that mouse was group 'C' or 'T' if that is what we want to investigate.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, I was just making sure I got it right. Thanks again for your answer.